# how to automate labeling of data in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, pie-chart

I would like to find a shortcut to labeling data since I am working with a large data set.

here's the data I'm charting from the large data set:

```
Nationality
Afghanistan      4
Albania         40
Algeria         60
Andorra          1
Angola          15
              ...
Uzbekistan       2
Venezuela       67
Wales          129
Zambia           9
Zimbabwe        13
Name: count, Length: 164, dtype: int64
```

And so far this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

the_data = pd.read_csv('fifa_data.csv')

plt.title('Percentage of Players from Each Country')

the_data['count'] = 1
Nations = the_data.groupby(['Nationality']).count()['count']

plt.pie(Nations)
plt.show()
```

creating the pie chart is easy and quick this way but I haven't figured out how to automatically label each country in the pie chart without having to label each data point one by one.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` plot function would automatic label the data for you

```
# count:
Nations = the_data.groupby('Nationality').size()

# plot data
Nations.plot.pie()

plt.title('Percentage of Players from Each Country')
plt.show()
```